# Best practice: Http response status code from server when client sends Conncetion: close?

Tags: http, http-headers, connection, http-response-codes

What should be http 1.1 response status code from server when client sends Conncetion: close in a header?
Where I can find any documentation?
For now I receive status 404 as a response when sending Get command with close connection header.

Comment: The response's Status Code is not related to the `Connection` header at all. *ANY* HTTP request *and/or* response can have `Connection: close` on it, regardless of the Status Code. If the client sends `Connection: close`, it tells the server to close the socket connection after sending the response. If the server sends `Connection: close`, it tells the client that the socket connection will be closed at the end of the response. A Status Code of 404 means the resource requested by the `GET` was not found on the server. That has nothing to do with whether the connection will be closed or not.

Comment: I suggest you read the HTTP 1.1 protocol spec, [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) (particularly [Section 14.10 Connection Header](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.10) and [Section 8 Connections](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-8)). And its successors, RFCs [7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230), [7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231), [7232](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232), [7233](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233), [7234](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234), and [7235](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235).